# How can i get the activity name in clearcase if i have the baseline and version number

Tags: clearcase

I am a beginner with CleaCase.

The view i was working in is now deleted, post delivery of the code changes. Only thing that is accessible now is activities.

I can get the list of activities by issuing "ct lsact " on the Integration Stream SDS

I have the following info from which i want to know which activity has my changes

```
--12-24T20:13  user     create version "/vob/abc/xyz/mno/src/hello.c@@/main/abc_1.0_integration/ver_2.0_integration/Mars_plm_1.0_SDS/**7**" (VER_2.0_BL21_09_01_2014_13_43.9104, Mars_abc1.0_mysqldb_07_01_2014_15_01.5788, VER_2.0_BL21_27_12_2013_19_07.4516, VER_2.0_BL21_24_12_2013_20_13.4521)
```

I want to find out which activity has the below version of the checked in file.

```
/vob/abc/xyz/mno/src/hello.c@@/main/abc_1.0_integration/ver_2.0_integration/Mars_plm_1.0_SDS/7
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use [cleartool describe](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) to see if the activity is displayed:

```
cleartool describe -l hello.c@@/main/...
```

Using [`fmt_ccase` options](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Ffmt_ccase.htm), you can display the activity directly:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[activity]p" hello.c@@/main/...
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC your solution will also do the work i found out the solution by issuing a grep `ct lsact -l | grep hello.c@@/main/... -B 5 -A 5 `

Comment: This one can save your grep: 
cleartool describe -fmt "%[activity]p" hello.c@@/main/...